# Change pop-over contentsize using navigationcontroller

Tags: iphone, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I want to show a popover with a custom contentsize.
I can do it doing like so

```
UINavigationController* popoverContent = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];


    UIView* popoverView = [[UIView alloc]  initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 800, 800)];

    popoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    popoverContent.view = popoverView;

    popoverContent.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(55, 55);
    UIPopoverController *pop = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];
    [pop presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft animated:YES];
```

but if I change the content to :

```
popoverContent.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:myViewController];
```

the

```
popoverContent.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(55, 55);
```

the size doesn't change at all.

How can I change the content size while using the navigation controller? 
Thanks

Comment: This is breaking my balls too. What the hell is up with it?

Answer (score 4):

Explicitly changing the popovers size works:

```
 [self.popoverController setPopoverContentSize:myView.size animated:YES];
```

But I agree that `contentSizeForViewInPopover` should work. It doesn't for me anyway.