# resize the UiPopoverController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I have created one `UIPopoverController`. Here, I can display the popover fine where the content view is a `UITableView`. When the popover is visible, I have to press a button and reload the tableview.

After that the tableview may increase it's height. I want to resize the popover when reload is performed.

Comment: what you tried paste the code

Comment: have you tried local notification to resize popoverview from parent view

Comment: have you considered **[self.yourPopViewController setPopoverContentSize:self.yourTableView.contentSize animated:YES];**

Comment: @AhmadAl-Kayyali it can use only for set the size dynamically.i want to resize popover with a method call

Comment: may be this link help you:                                   
                                                                     1> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459834/change-pop-over-contentsize-using-navigationcontroller

Answer (score 0):

In your ViewController.m file, add the following method:

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{
self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(tableInPopover.frame.size.width,tableInPopover.frame.size.height) ;}
```

Hope this helps